# String Array for Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, jgrasp

I have a question regarding making String arrays in Java. I want to create a String array that will store a specific word in each compartment of the string array. For example, if my program scanned `What is your deal?` I want the word `What` and `your` to be in the array so I can display it later.

How can I code this? Also, how do I display it with `System.out.println();`?

Okey so, here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class OddSentence {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String sentence, word, oddWord;
        StringTokenizer st;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);


        System.out.println("Enter sentence: ");
        sentence = scan.nextLine();

        sentence = sentence.substring(0, sentence.length()-1);
        st = new StringTokenizer(sentence);

        word = st.nextToken();


        while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word = st.nextToken();
            if(word.length() % 2 != 0) 

        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

I wanted my program to count each word in a sentence. If the word has odd numbers of letter, it will be displayed.

Comment: What have you tried to do so far? Have you looked through the available methods in the `String` class itself?

Comment: What criteria are you using to determine what words should be in the array? As in, why are only `What` and `your` contained in the array?

Comment: If you use `next` instead of `nextLine`, the `Scanner` will do your tokenisation and you can just grab your input in a loop.  Then you don't need either `split` or your `StringTokenizer`.

Comment: @DavidWallace How would I implement it in a loop if i change the `nextLine` to `next` and would it display all the words?

Comment: `while(scan.hasNext()) { word = scan.next(); if(word.length() % 2 != 0)  { // do stuff } }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with what the others have said, you should use String.split(), which separates all elements on the provided character and stores each element in the array.

```
String str = "This is a string";
String[] strArray = str.split(" ");   //splits at all instances of the space & stores in array
for (int i = 0; i < strArray.length(); i++) {
  if((strArray[i].length() % 2) == 0) {  //if there is an even number of characters in the string
    System.out.println(strArray[i]);     //print the string
  }
}
```

Output:

> This is string

If you want to print the string when it has an odd number of characters, simply change `if((strArray[i].length() % 2) == 0)` to `if((strArray[i].length() % 2) != 0)`

This will give you just **a** as the output (the only word in the string with an odd number of characters).

Comment: Instead of using the for loop, we could utilize

    Arrays.deepToString(Object[] args);

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you've given alone, I would say use `#split()`

```
String example = "What is your deal?"
String[] spl = example.split(" ");
/*
  args[0] = What
  args[1] = is
  args[2] = your
  args[3] = deal?
*/
```

To display the array as a whole, use `Arrays.toString(Array);`

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(spl));
```

Comment: [`Arrays#toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString) would be a better method of displaying the array in this way.

Comment: Actually, I have a Scanner so that when the program is ran, it will ask the user to enter a sentence and what ever the sentence is, I will use a StringTokenizer to go through each word in a sentence.

Comment: From the Javadoc for `StringTokenizer` - "StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead."

Comment: @PaulRichter That is what I have in my answer (I did say list originally, but changed it within the first minute).

Comment: @Rogue Ah yes, I see that now. I'm on my phone; sadly it doesn't auto publish changes until I refresh the screen.

Answer (score 1):

To read and split use `String.split()`

```
final String input = "What is your deal?";
final String[] words = input.split(" ");
```

To print them to e.g. command line, use a loop:

```
for (String s : words) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

or when working with Java 8 use a `Stream`:

```
Stream.of(words).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let `input` be your input string. Then:

```
String[] words = input.split(" ");
```